# .htaccess rule is "not working"

Tags: .htaccess

This is my url:
http://www.mychoice.com/apppages.php?type=iphone&title=Best-Audiobooks-100&id=2617

I want to rewrite as like that:
www.mychoice.com/app/iphone/Best-Audiobooks-100/2617.html

I am using this rule for Rewrite:
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ category.php?type=$1&cat=$2&catid=$3 [L]

but its not working. always redirect to 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the quantifier `+` for first two capture groups.

```
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ category.php?type=$1&cat=$2&catid=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

You have also changed the query parameter names in your substitution URL. If the target URL actually is

> http://www.mychoice.com/apppages.php?type=iphone&title=Best-Audiobooks-100&id=2617

then the `RewriteRule` should be

```
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /apppages.php?type=$1&title=$2&id=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```